# No route found for "GET /numbers"

Tags: symfony

I created a controller called NumbersController. Right now I want it to dispaly something that I put on url. The controller looks like this:

```
class NumbersController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_numbers")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($number)
    {
        return array('number' => $number);
    } }
```

I created a folder in view called Numbers and a file `index.html.twig` that contain just `{{ number }}`.

Somehow here is a problem with the routes and when I goto `http://127.0.0.1/SERVER/symfony/web/app_dev.php/numbers/2` for example I get `No route found for "GET /numbers`.

I'm pretty sure that I understood how routes works from the default examples from symfony2 but I just can't figure out why don't work with a new controller.

```
_numbers:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/NumbersController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /numbers
```

Comment: Route annotation should be '@Route("/numbers/{number}") unless you have route annotation at class.

Comment: I get the same error with this route too.

Comment: So you have prefix. In that case your route should be `@Route("/{number}")` 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-prefix

Comment: Oh, that's happening when you use things that don't understand 100%. Now, at least I'm sure that I understood the prefixes. Thank you for your help and for the link. I would like you to post that solution as a reply to be able to chose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have prefix. In that case your route should be @Route("/{number}") 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-prefix